# Catching an awkward string using Regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings consisting of a format such as the following:

```
test p * * * * * test2
another test c * * * * * finished test
test4 * * *
```

What I want to do is identify cases where the asterisks are following a single letter character and merge them with the character to form a whole "word" without the spaces between them. A regexp approach would be necessary to identify this specific pattern within each string.

I do not want them to be merged if there is no isolated character before it. So taking the examples above the output should look like:

```
test p***** test2
another test c***** finished test
test4 ***
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, I am very rusty with my regexp in Python.

Comment: Does this have to do be done with a regexp? It can't do a variable number of space removals when the dependency is only before the first one.

Comment: You should do this in two steps. First remove all the spaces between the asterisks, since that's not dependent on whether there's an isolated letter before them. Then merge the asterisks with the single letter before them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with regex, the basic process is to remove whitespace before the `*` character (`re.sub(r"[^\S\n]\*", '*', value)`), *but* you don't want to do it immediately after another word. So, also require that a `*` or a character comes before.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

def removeWhitespace(value: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r"(?<=\s(\*|\w))[^\S\n]\*", '*', value)
```

Some tests:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest

from main import removeWhitespace

class RemoveWhitespaceTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        actual = removeWhitespace("test p * * * * * test2")
        expected = "test p***** test2"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test2(self):
        actual = removeWhitespace("another test c * * * * * finished test")
        expected = "another test c***** finished test"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test3(self):
        actual = removeWhitespace("test4 * * *")
        expected = "test4 ***"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    def test4(self):
        actual = removeWhitespace("hello world")
        expected = "hello world"
        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

Results

```
$ python3.7 -m unittest tests.py 
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

You don't mention this in your data, but this doesn't capture at the beginning of the string. If this is needed, hopefully you're now far enough down the track to figure it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a regular expression like

```
(?<= )(\w)((?: \*)+)(?= )
```

which will give you two groups: group 1, `(\w)` - the single character, and group 2, `((?: \*)+)` - the asterisks with spaces. (The extras in the above regular expression are to ensure that the whole statement is both preceded and followed by a whitespace). Then strip group 2 of whitespaces and return the concatenation of group 1 and group 2?

So, something like

```
import re

input_string = 'test p * * * * * test2\nanother test c * * * * * finished test\ntest4 * * *'

def remove_whitespaces(input):
    start_char = input.group(1)
    asterisks = input.group(2)
    asterisks = asterisks.replace(' ', '')
    return start_char + asterisks

return_string = re.sub(r'(?<= )(\w)((?: \*)+)(?= )', remove_whitespaces, input_string)
print(return_string)
```

output:

```
test p***** test2
another test c***** finished test
test4 * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work, it first match *'s with or without leading character. Then using `ptrn.sub` it remove spaces on matched pattern

```py
import re
ptrn = re.compile(r"(\s\w)?(\s\*)+")
text = '''test p * * * * * test2
another test c * * * * * finished test
test4 * * *'''

ptrn.sub(lambda x: " %s"%(x[0].replace(" ","")), text)
```

**output**

```
test p***** test2
another test c***** finished test
test4 ***
```